# How to insert variable as text in Python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Here is my code, it is to insert data into a database, , if i use numbers it works, but not with text, how do i solve it? I think i need to put «data» between two quotation marks ", how do i do that?
Thanks

```
def aggiungi():

    print('funzione \'aggiungi\'')

    conn = db.connect(NOMEDB)
    print
    "Database aperto con successo";

    cognome, nome, indirizzo, mail, tel_fisso, tel_cell = input(
        "Inserire cognome, nome, indirizzo, mail, tel_fisso, tel_cell (separati da virgola): ").split(",")
    dati = cognome + "," + nome + "," + indirizzo + "," + mail + "," + tel_fisso + "," + tel_cell

    conn.execute("INSERT INTO contatti (cognome, nome, "
                 f"indirizzo, mail, tel_fisso, tel_cell) VALUES ({dati})");


    conn.commit()
    print ("Records created successfully)")
    conn.close()
    return
```

Comment: You can put quotes inside a string by escaping them, e.g. `\"`

Comment: @Samwise you mean like i should write ....VALUES ({\"dati\"})?

Comment: `\"{dati}\"` if you want the result of evaluating `dati` to be in quotation marks in the query.

Comment: you can use `" "` inside `' '` like `'funzione "aggiungi" '` or `' '` inside `" "` like `"funzione 'aggiungi' "`. And the same you can do inside your query: `f'... "{dati}" ...'`. OR you should rather use `exceute(' ... VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)', (cognome, nome, indirizzo, mai, tel_fisso, tel_cell))` and it should add `""` in expected places

Comment: how did you defined table? If table expecte number then you can't use text with letters.

Comment: better show FULL error message - maybe your problem is different then you think. Maybe you don't need `" "` but maybe database is defined for numbers and it can't get letters.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `+` to concatenate strings `"INSERT INTO contatti (cognome, nome, "` and `f"indirizzo, mail, tel_fisso, tel_cell) VALUES ({dati})"`.

However, I should point out that this approach is highly dangerous for the security of your database, as it could be attacked with SQL injection. Basically, you are inserting a generic string into your query, without checking its content.
For instance, a malicious user could add this string for `tel_cell`:

`3290000000);SELECT * FROM contatti --`

This would cause your database to execute whatever query the malicious user likes.

Solution is to prepare your query. Further readings on this:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html (see last example before "Module functions and constants")

https://www.websec.ca/kb/sql_injection

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but i'm not concerned about attacks, because this is a program that i have to do for school, and I don't think my teacher is gonna hack my database.

Also i don't have a + where you said there should be because pycharm has automatically put it like that to respect a width of the text